# Filter an array of objects by key and/or value in child object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have an array of users that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Melody Adam",
        "interests": {
            "hockey": "somewhat",
            "football": "yes"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Antonio Rutledge",
        "interests": {
            "football": "somewhat",
            "curling": "no",
            "polevaulting": "somewhat"
        }
    },
]
```

How would I go about to filter this array by things in the `interests` object, e.g. when the value is `"somewhat"` or when the key is `"football"`? I'm trying to wrap my head around Array.prototype.filter and Array.prototype.reduce, but still don't quite get it. I know that I could use something like `users.filter(({ name }) => name === "Melody Adam")` to filter based on things at the "top level" of the object, but not keeping the array intact when going one step "deeper" (if there is any better/correct terms for this, please let me know).

Comment: `users.filter(({ interests }) => interests[key] === value)`?

Comment: In addition to @jonrsharpe's answer, you might want to look at `Array.prototype.includes()`, `Object.keys()`, `Object.values()`, ...

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, but what if don't know the key or the value?

Comment: Then how are you expecting to filter anything?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I mean one of them. If I were to for example filter on `interests` only, I could go `interests.filter((key, value) => key === "football")`, but I can't wrap my head around when the initial level is one step up, so to say (the main array in this case).

Answer (score 0):

```
var testarr = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Melody Adam",
    "interests": {
      "hockey": "somewhat",
      "football": "yes"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Antonio Rutledge",
    "interests": {
      "football": "somewhat",
      "curling": "no",
      "polevaulting": "somewhat"
    }
  },
];

var search = "somewhat";
var selectedItems = [];
jQuery.each(testarr, function (i, item) {
  if (item && search && item.interests && item.interests.football) {
    var value = item.interests.football.trim().toLowerCase();
    if (search === value) {
      selectedItems.push(item);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, vanilla JS only.